# Get scaling factor of an image when the image goes out of grid

Tags: wpf, image, grid, scale, out

I have a grid that contains an image.

```
<Grid Name="grid1">
    <Image Name="image1" Stretch="None" Source="C:\Users\User\Desktop\image.jpg"/>
</Grid>
```

If the size of image was greater than the size of the grid, I want to scale it manually by render transform to fit the grid. I don't want to use Stretch="Fill" because I need the scale factor.
Is there any way to detect the situation that an UIElement goes out of view?
I need your help.

Comment: Language? Context? You are missing some information / tags...

Answer (score 3):

You could simply set the `Stretch` property to `Uniform` (or perhaps `Fill`) and calculate the scaling factor from the `ActualWidth` of the Image and the `Width` of the ImageSource, whenever you need it. The sample below does the calculation in a SizeChanged handler, but it could be anywhere else.

```
<Image Name="image1" Stretch="Uniform" Source="C:\Users\User\Desktop\image.jpg"
       SizeChanged="ImageSizeChanged"/>
```

The calculation looks like this:

```
private void ImageSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var scale = image1.ActualWidth / image1.Source.Width;
}
```

As `Uniform` is the default value of the `Stretch` property, you wouldn't have to set it at all.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you would want to rescale your image manually when WPF can do it for you...

Instead of putting the image straight into the grid, use a **[Viewbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox.aspx)** control:

```
<Grid Name="grid1">
    <Viewbox>
        <Image Name="image1" Stretch="None" Source="C:\Users\User\Desktop\image.jpg"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

The Viewbox will automatically scale the picture to fit inside the grid...

Comment: Wouldn't you achieve exactly the same without the Viewbox, but with setting `Image.Stretch` to `Uniform` (which is the default value of `Viewbox.Stretch`)?